# RegEx for converting from Doxygen to XMLDoc

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace

I have some source with backslash-style Doxygen comments (*eg. `\brief Text`*), and am trying to use Visual Studio 2013 RegExs to help convert to XML Docs (*eg. `<summary>Text</summary>`*).

But I've run into problems where it captures an end of line I want to avoid:

Here's my Current Find/Replace, and the result:

```
Find: \\brief.\s(?<brief>.*)[\r?\n]{1}
```

*Intention: Look for `\brief`, whitespace, a set of characters (captured as "brief"), exactly 1 newline.*

```
Replace: <summary>${brief}</summary>
```

*Intention: Replace with XML tags, the captured "brief" text, specifically NOT including the newline.*

**Actual result:**

```
/// \brief  My Brief Text for this function
///

/// <summary> My Brief Text for this function
</summary>///
```

It appears that the newline was captured as part of the Tagged text, even though I tried to avoid that.
I'm trying to get the `</summary>` closing tag on the same line as the rest of the text.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `[\r?\n]{1}` checks for one of `\r`, `?`, or `\n` (and the `{1}` is superfluous).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid newline characters as part of the capture, you can search for:

```
\\brief\s*([^\n\r])+
```

You can replace with `<summary>$1</summary>`

The `[^\n\r]` is a negated character class that matches any character that is neither a newline nor a carriage return. By adding the `+` quantifier, we manage to match the whole line.

**What were the problems with the original?**

1. the `.\s` is the first problem. The dot matches the space character, then there is no space left to match for the `\s`
2. the `?` in the `[\r?\n]` serves no purpose. It does not make the `\r` optional, but says that a literal question mark is one of the allowable chars to be matched at that position.
3. the `{1}` is redundant, as a `[charclass]` only matches one character unless it is followed by a quantifier.

Comment: Would `$` work in VS "as usual", or does it only match end-of-story?

Comment: Thanks... I modified your expression a little to: `\\brief\s*([^\n\r]+)`, and that seems to be working.  However, I don't yet see why my original expression failed.

Comment: @abelenky Ha, meeting of minds, I had modified it too. Let me have a look at your original.

Comment: The original regex may have included `\r` in the `.*` part (greedy behavior), stopping only at the slightly malformed end condition because of the `\n` inside that.

Comment: @abelenky I revised the answer to explain why the original didn't perform. Hope this works for you. :)

Comment: @abelenky It was a pleasure, nice meeting you. :)

Comment: Shouldn't OP try to match the string `\n\r` instead of the character class?  Why use a character class here?

Comment: @abelenky And looking at your tags it looks like I could learn an amazing amount from you in C and C++ :)

Comment: @David Not sure I understand your comment, what specific regex do you suggest?